# Reference request for instantons

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, noncommutative-geometry

I've been researching instantons lately and I'd like to learn more about them but would like some help finding what to read. I have read about the ADHM equations and their noncommutative analogues. But this only works for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^4_{NC}$. How do we extend these to other manifolds? For example, how can we get instantons on the torus $\mathbb{T}^4 = \mathbb{R}^4 / \Gamma$? Or a complex torus $\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$? One would think to allow some sort of periodicity which agrees with the lattice (forgive the non-technical terminology), but how is this done and/or what are the obstructions to this?

The ADHM construction is such a beautiful thing and I hope there are analogues for other manifolds.

In summary I am looking for papers/notes/books to read that give an expository and/or technical explanation about finding instantons on other manifolds, particularly on the (complex, ideally) torus, which hopefully have a hand in the ADHM pot as well. And I'm not a physicist nor an analyst so the more algebro-/complex-geometric the better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you don't mind a bit of noncommutative differential geometry, then you can take a look at this expository article by Landi and Van Suijlekom for an account of instantons on noncommutative (real) $4$-tori: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0603053
The heart of the matter is that if you apply Rieffel's strict deformation quantisation to a compact $\mathbb{T}^N$-manifold $X$, then any $\mathbb{T}^N$-equivariant object over $X$ (e.g., an equivariant vector bundle) can be deformed to an analogous noncommutative-geometric object over the deformation of $X$.

Comment: It sounds like you're probably past this, but you might take a peek at section 13.2 of http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Theory-Fields-Valery-Rubakov/dp/0691059276

Comment: @Branimir - Thanks for the article, and I don't mind looking at noncommutative things. I actually am sort of searching in that direction. Though I find it is hard to grasp sometimes without a proper and thorough introduction.

Comment: @Steve - Thanks for the recommendation as well. I am always willing to read something even if just to solidify an idea especially if it is well written.

Comment: You might also look at Chapter 8 of Ward and Wells' book on twistors.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good  starting place for your question regarding the moduli space for a  flat 4-torus is the `Fourier-Mukai'
correspondence which came out of work of Nahm and which relates the moduli space over one such torus to that of its dual torus.  See section 3.2 of the book`The Geometry of Four-Manifolds' by Donaldson and Kronheimer, and more recently  (and chosen somewhat at random from  a google search):
http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~jardim/publicados/crelle03.pdf